# Dynamically created range slider label won't show selected range

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hey I'm using jQuery mobile and have the following code :

```
var newLabel = '<label for="slider-1"></label>';
var newSlider = '<input type="range" name="slider-1"
class="product_slider" style="display:none; margin:20px;"
value="60" min="0" max="100" />';
$(newLabel).insertAfter($(this).parent());
$(newSlider).insertAfter($(this).parent()).slider();
//Tries i've made :
// $(this).parent().trigger('create');
// $(this).parent().parent().trigger('create');
// $(this).parent().parent().trigger('refresh');
```

Now this code does generate the slider but doesn't turn the label into an input that shows the selected range.

I'ver tried `trigger('create')`, tried refreshing after creating, tried `.page()`, but none worked.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my problem was that little `display:none;`.

For some reason it affects the creation of the label into the input. wierd since i added it because it showed the regular range together with the new one, but right now it doesn't. This code worked :

```
    var newSlider = '<label for="slider-1"></label><input type="range" name="slider-1"  class="product_slider" style=" margin:20px;" value="60" min="0" max="100" />';
$(newSlider).insertAfter($(this).parent());
$(this).parent().parent().trigger("create");
```